# How to make same height of all responsive images in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

The first image of the row doesn't have the same height as the other ones. I am using Bootstrap `.img-responsive`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="down-content">
        <div class="haber">
            <!--HABER 1-->
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div id="haber1">
                    <div id="haberimg1">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.avukatwebsite.net/public/_uploads/photos/temalar/avukat-web-site-tema-1.jpg" >
                    </div>
                    <div id="haberyazi1">
                        <h3>Kanser Affetmedi...</h3>
                        <p>Sanssiz genc Kanser yüzünden öldü...</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn">Devamini Oku...</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--HABER 2-->
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div id="haber2">
                    <div id="haberimg2">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://medicare.bold-themes.com/clinic/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/12/shutterstock_288977717-1200x800.jpg" >
                    </div>
                    <div id="haberyazi2">
                        <h3>Sizofreni Salgini</h3>
                        <p>Türkiyede ki Sizofren sayisinda artis görüldü...</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn">Devamini Oku...</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            /* we deleted the other parts because of mostly code problem */
        </div>
        <!--HABER BÖLÜMÜ BITIS-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap CSS**

```
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This is the issue:
[image]

Comment: set min-height:100%

Comment: It didn't work sir.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions. Here is a couple of similar solutions. First you would need to create a div that scales responsively. This can be achieved with:

```
.img-wrap {
  height:0;
  // adjust the padding to change the aspect ratio of the div
  padding-bottom:60%;
}
```

you can then either add a background image to the `.image-wrap` element with `background-size:cover`. Or you could place an image inside `.image-wrap` and then `position:absolute;` it inside `.image-wrap` and add `object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to **use** images that have the **same width** and the **same height**! (You avoid a lot of problems and there is no need to fix something with CSS)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
        <button class="btn">More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
        <button class="btn">More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
        <button class="btn">More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
        <button class="btn">More</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

You have to set a fixed height to the `img` parent div and then set `height:100%` to the `img` Check below Snippet:

```css
.haberImg {
    height: 75px;
}

.haberImg img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">


  <div class="down-content">
    <div class="haber">


      <!--HABER 1-->
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div id="haber1">
          <div id="haberimg1" class="haberImg">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.avukatwebsite.net/public/_uploads/photos/temalar/avukat-web-site-tema-1.jpg"></div>
          <div id="haberyazi1">
            <h3>Kanser Affetmedi...</h3>
            <p>Sanssiz genc Kanser yüzünden öldü...</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Devamini Oku...</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--HABER 2-->
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div id="haber2">
          <div id="haberimg2" class="haberImg">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://medicare.bold-themes.com/clinic/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/12/shutterstock_288977717-1200x800.jpg"></div>
          <div id="haberyazi2">
            <h3>Sizofreni Salgini</h3>
            <p>Türkiyede ki Sizofren sayisinda artis görüldü...</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Devamini Oku...</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Answer 2:**

You have to set a fixed height to the `img` parent div as the smallest img height and then add `overflow:hidden`.  Check below Snippet:

```css
.haberImg {
    height: 80px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">


  <div class="down-content">
    <div class="haber">


      <!--HABER 1-->
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div id="haber1">
          <div id="haberimg1" class="haberImg">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.avukatwebsite.net/public/_uploads/photos/temalar/avukat-web-site-tema-1.jpg"></div>
          <div id="haberyazi1">
            <h3>Kanser Affetmedi...</h3>
            <p>Sanssiz genc Kanser yüzünden öldü...</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Devamini Oku...</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--HABER 2-->
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div id="haber2">
          <div id="haberimg2" class="haberImg">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://medicare.bold-themes.com/clinic/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/12/shutterstock_288977717-1200x800.jpg"></div>
          <div id="haberyazi2">
            <h3>Sizofreni Salgini</h3>
            <p>Türkiyede ki Sizofren sayisinda artis görüldü...</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Devamini Oku...</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give your images same class and add height.

Trick: avoid of giving height with `pixels` because getting issue in small screen instead give height with `rem` or 
`percentage`

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy actually, use display grid and grid-auto-columns: 1fr.

Comment: Please post a detailed answer, how to use this `grid` and `grid-auto-columns: 1fr`